# Transfering uintN data types from C to Java (Socket Programing)

Tags: java, c, sockets, unsigned-integer

I have a requirement to send data from native program written in C through Sockets, namely the winsock interface. That data is then received by a java program. The Java program receives a packet of data of which it know the order and makes some processing. It takes the int received from the socket.Read() like `client_socket.getInputStream().read()`

A processing of that int data returned from the Read() is parsed to get the data types expected. Basically it is a slicing of the bulk data received. I can only assume that the read() functions reads 4 bytes at a time (the 32 bit java int size). So I proceed to separate that 4 bytes(8 bits not the Java type) into 4 Java shorts so i can correctly represent the unsigned values they represent.
After i have the 4 shorts if i know i want eg a uint16, i just concatenate the 2 shorts

The problem is somewhere i am doing some wrong bit manipulation that is not working out as i thought it would.
The C code and the Java code is below and its really simple even though it does not work. The output is something which i can't understand why it is the way it is.

```
0 0   0 0    0 1     0 0     0 2     0 0     0 3     0 0     0 4 {...}
```

The C code redacted the initialization part:

```
uint16_t buffer[255] = {};
uint16_t *current_pointer = buffer;
for(uint16_t index = 0; index < 255; index++) {
    *current_pointer = index;
    current_pointer++;
}
Write(client_socket, (char *)buffer, sizeof(buffer));
```

The java code also redacted:

```
public final short[] JavaIntToUint8Array(int unsigned_int) {
    return new short[] { (short)((unsigned_int & 0xFF000000L) >> 24),
                (short)((unsigned_int & 0x00FF0000L) >> 16),
                (short)((unsigned_int & 0x0000FF00L) >> 8),
                (short)((unsigned_int & 0x000000FFL))};
}
public final int[] JavaIntToUint16(int unsigned_int) {
    short uint8_array[] = JavaIntToUint8Array(unsigned_int);
    return new int[] { (int)(uint8_array[0] << 8) | (int)uint8_array[1],            
        (int)(uint8_array[2] << 8) | (int)(uint8_array[3]) };
}
```

...

```
while (index < 255) {
        read_data = data_input.read();
        System.out.print(" ");
        System.out.print(JavaIntToUint16(read_data)[0]);
        System.out.print(" ");
        System.out.print(JavaIntToUint16(read_data)[1]);
        System.out.print("\t");
        index++;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest approach to reading unsigned short numbers is to use DataInput.readUnsignedShort().

```
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(data_input);
int num = dis.readUnsignedShort();
```

This uses big-endian or network endian.  If you are using little endian (e.g. on an x86/x64 processor) you can change the byte order yourself or using ByteBuffer to do it.

```
// using NIO
SocketChannel sc = SocketChannel.open(new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 12345));
ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(32*1024).order(ByteBuffer.LITTE_ENDIAN));
while(sc.read(bb) >= 0) {
    bb.flip();
    while(bb.remaining() > 1) {
       int num = bb.getShort() & 0xFFFF;
    }
    bb.compact();
}
```

Do you really need to send a stream of unsigned short values?  A more often used stream is a unsigned bytes and these are simpler.

Comment: Shouldn't sc.read(bb) > 0 be sc.read(bb) >= 0? read may return 0.

Comment: Not if its blocking, but changed it anyway. ;)

Comment: java is so brilliant. I can change the endiannes in the buffer itself. Also lots of things about the buffer library i didnt know

Comment: also the stream contains multiple data types. I expect some order and "parse" the type accordingly.

Comment: You can getShort, int, float, double, char and bytes.

Comment: i know. actually the Bytebuffer does exactly what the question asks and is why i am going to give it the right answer. There is a detail in the question that is not written, which is the fact that what i will receive is structured data, meaning lots of data types. I dont think i can flip the bb as you suggest because i depend on the order that the data arrives. I will create a byte buffer for each var i receive.

Comment: You should be able able to create a ByteBuffer which is used for the entire session if you want.  I use it for parsing text and binary and never need more than one.  Perhaps you could ask another question and give an example of the data structure you need to parse.

Answer (score 3):

> *I can only assume that the read() functions reads 4 bytes at a time
>   (the 32 bit java int size)*

No, you can't assume that. The [documentation for `InputStream.read()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read%28%29) says :

> public abstract int read()
>                     throws IOException
>
> Reads the next byte of data from the input stream. The value byte is returned as an int in the range 0 to 255. If no byte is available
>   because the end of the stream has been reached, the value -1 is
>   returned. This method blocks until input data is available, the end of
>   the stream is detected, or an exception is thrown.
>
> ```
> A subclass must provide an implementation of this method.
>
> Returns:
>     the next byte of data, or -1 if the end of the stream is reached.
> ```

Comment: so this means that the 4 number i am seeing are actually the bytes themselves. If so that is so simple and i feel bad